# Monitor ssh connection and get login user information from authorized_keys

Tags: ssh, rsa

is there any way to use `.ssh/authorized_keys` to get the corresponding login user's email when the linux system is connected through `id_rsa.pub`?

I try to use the content in `/var/log/auth.log` while I can't find the direct relationship between the records and `.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is off-topic. Stackoverflow is for programming questions. Try superuser.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last column of ssh public key is [just a comment field](https://serverfault.com/questions/743548/what-significance-does-the-user-host-at-the-end-of-an-ssh-public-key-file-hold/743566#743566) and it is not present in the private key used to log in nor in the public key send to the server during the authentication attempt.

The comment in the server authorized keys can be completely different than the comment in the clients public key.

You can find the connection between the keys in `authorized_keys` and in the logs, but you need to convert the keys to fingerprints first using

```
ssh-keygen -lf ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Answer (score 5):

May be someone needs it. Next command prints information about the ssh key that was used for a current session. The key is taken from a standard comment block from `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

For instance, `somebody@test.com` will be printed for a key that looks this way: `cyb5OrLRv0VR6gZev8...KdECf7Q== somebody@test.com`

**Command:**

```
export CURRENT_SSH_USER=$(grep $(grep $(grep '@'$(who -m | awk '{print $2}') <(ps -ef) | head -1 | awk '{print $3}')']: Accepted publickey for' /var/log/auth.log | head -1 | awk '{print $16}') <(cat ~/.ssh/authorized_keys | xargs -n1 -I% bash -c 'ssh-keygen -l -f /dev/stdin <<<"%"') | tail -1 | awk '{print $3}')
```

**The command above does these steps:**

1. `who -m` Only hostname and user associated with stdin.
2. Taking pseudo terminal slave e.g. `pts/2` for a current user from the prev. command.
3. Searching for `pts/2` in a list of processes `ps -ef` and extracting its pid.
4. Looking for the pid, e.g. `21996` in `/var/log/auth.log` in lines like this one: 
   `Jul 22 01:50:39 whatever-i-12345 sshd[21996]: Accepted publickey for ubuntu from 10.10.10.10 port 40411 ssh2: RSA SHA256:V4DD10NklAAAAAHNgxaurm1qaq/TOTejNjXMQABABAB`. Be sure you have proper logging enabled.
5. Once fingerprint `SHA256:V4DD10NklAAAAAHNgxaurm1qaq/TOTejNjXMQABABAB` is found, it matches it with the line from `/.ssh/authorized_keys` retrieves info about a name from a comment block.

**Notes:**

Tested only on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-62-generic x86_64)